# Why is my css style not formatting properly when I use runat="server" in the unordered list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

What I'm trying to do is make a list item visible when the Admin logs in within the navigation section. I am unable to use the AD so I can use roles so I'm using SQL server to to control which users have access to what. I found a way to make the list item visible once that admin logs in, but to do so, I had to use runat="server" within the unordered list. Once I use this, the css formatting that I use for the navigation is no longer. How am I able to fix this problem and achieve what I would like to do?  This is my code within the master page..

```
<section runat="server" id="login">
   <asp:LoginView id="loginview" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
      <LoggedInTemplate>
         <p id="paragraph">
            Welcome,
            <asp:LoginName ID="loginName" runat="server" CssClass="username" />
            </a>!
            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" />
            <ul runat="server" id="menu">
               <li><a href="~/Dashboard.aspx">Dashboard</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/DeliveredDeals.aspx">Delivered Deals</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/DealTracking.aspx">Deal Tracking</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" id="allUsers" href="~/Users.aspx" visible="false">Users</a></li>
            </ul>
         </p>
      </LoggedInTemplate>
   </asp:LoginView>
</section>
```

This is how I have it set up. Once I remove the `runat="server"` from the `<ul>` I'm no longer able to view the new list item (allUsers) but the formatting is back. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks you.

Here is the css..

```
/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the css? It sounds like you have an css id selector `#menu`. With the `runat="server"`, ASP.Net changes the id of the element.

Comment: I have added the css. And so far thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `runat="server"`, the ID will be modified via ASP.NET resulting in your css issue. You should change your `ul` to use a class instead of styling it based on the id.

```
<ul runat="server" class="menu">
    <!--Html-->
</ul>
```

Css:

```
/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 ul.menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
ul.menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul.menu li a {
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

Comment: That all makes sense. Thank you for the tip and the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you add runat="server" ASP.NET will add a prefix to your ID which will most likely break the CSS

For Example :

If you place your element in `<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"><asp:Content>`

It will change `<ul runat="server" id="menu">` to `<ul id="MainContent_menu">`

So check the page source then adjust your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using a css class instead of and ID for that purpose. Then you don't have to worry about .NET adding names to the style setting part of your element dynamically, thus making the css easier to deal with.

Should look something like this in other words:

```
<ul runat="server" class="menu">
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```